# I'll leave you (Text message)

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I texted my friend and said:

Hey, are you free to talk?

He said:

Sorry, I'm working on my science project.

I said: OK, ***I'll leave you.***

Does the highlighted sentence sound correct and natural in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

> I'll leave you alone [for now]
>
> I'll leave you be
>   *or*
>   I'll leave you to it

"I'll leave you"
is not *hugely* wrong, but it does have hints of
"I'm packing my bags & moving out."